# SQL query for distinct ids with the highest day

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the distinct ids with the latest day.

from this

```
user | day
-----------
1.   | 2021-12-20
3.   | 2021-12-02
1.   | 2021-12-09
3.   | 2021-12-01
3.   | 2021-12-09
1.   | 2021-12-07
2.   | 2021-12-12
```

to this

```
user | day
-----------
1.   | 2021-12-20
3.   | 2021-12-09
2.   | 2021-12-12
```

Answer (score 0):

One common approach uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY day DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT user, day
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If a given user could have the same max date appearing more than once, and you want to report all such records in the output, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` above with `RANK`.

Comment: That worked, thanks!